# Chrome Browser internal URLS for tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I know there are a lot of interest built-in URLS such as can be seen here chrome://chrome-urls/

Is there one that will show me all the tabs I have open and the title? 
That would be great for switching back and forth when I have probably 80 tabs open on about 5 or 6 different windows.

Also, is there one that will show which tab is using the most memory or CPU, or which one is currently playing audio?

Examples of use: 1) I use Windows Task Manager and see one Chrome task using 384K memory. How do I know which tab that is? 
2) You hear some video playing, and you want to stop it as soon as possible, but you are having trouble finding out which tab it is on.  (Looking for the small speaker icon is not good enough when you have 80 tabs open).